# PHP Netbeans - New Project from Existing Sources asking for an Index file?

Tags: php, netbeans6.5, new-project

I'm trying to create a new project in NetBeans PHP from existing sources.  When I try to create a new project, it asks me for the location of an Index File.  What is an Index File in the context of NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index file is the starting file for your debugging sessions. Normally it's the index.php in your application root. When you set it, it will be the default starting point when you press debug in NetBeans.

Comment: Oh that kind of index file!  Gag...it must be Friday...Thanks!